# How to call static methods in fragment and activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, retrofit2, dagger-2

I have an **api method** call that is called either in **activities** our **fragment**, the problem is that I need to have two equal methods with only the type(**BaseActivity** our **BaseFragment**) changing like this:

```
fun <T> BaseActivity.callAPI(call: Call<T>?, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit) {
    callAPI(call, onSucceed, {})
}

fun <T> BaseFragment.callAPI(call: Call<T>?, listener: BaseFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit) {
    callAPI(call, listener, onSucceed, {})
}
```

Is there a way to only have one **method** that does not include passing a parameter if its a fragment our an activity

Comment: Well I guess you could technically use `LifecycleOwner` o-o

Comment: Can you post an example above? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: Honestly, personally I just wouldn't have these extension functions at all. You might want to encapsulate the logic of calling to the API in a separate class, for example a ViewModel (in AAC).

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't go this way as this one differentiates between Activity and Fragment - they both are very different.

This is way to go but I wouldn't do that:

```
fun <T> Any.callAPI(call: Call<T>?, listener: BaseFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit) {
    when(this){
       is BaseFragment -> performCall(call, listener, onSucceed, {})
       is BaseActivity -> performCall(call, onSucceed, {})
    }
}


fun <T> BaseActivity.performCall(call: Call<T>?, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit, onError: (errorCode: String) -> Unit) {
    NetworkManager.instance.performCall(call,
        object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<T> {
            override fun onSuccess(body: T?) {
                onSucceed(body)
            }

            override fun onError(errorCode: String?) {}

            override fun onTwoFactorRequired() {
                onAuthenticationNeeded()
            }
        }) { onAppUpdateNeeded() }
}

fun <T> BaseFragment.performCall(call: Call<T>?, onSucceed: (T?) -> Unit, onError: (errorCode: String) -> Unit) {
        NetworkManager.instance.performCall(call,
            object : NetworkManager.OnRequestCallback<T> {
                override fun onSuccess(body: T?) {
                    onSucceed(body)
                }

                override fun onError(errorCode: String?) {}

                override fun onTwoFactorRequired() {
                    onAuthenticationNeeded()
                }
            }) { onAppUpdateNeeded() }
    }
```

Comment: @José Nobre yeah let's do it.

Comment: shared the rest of my code in the question. My callApi() is getting an error of the method cannot be applied to Any

Comment: @JoséNobre check it now, if this doesn't help post error

Comment: I change callApi() method name to performCall()

Comment: it looks wrong but i don't know why it had up vote .because, fragment is sub-activity and would 2 condition be true.but i am not sure.

Comment: @Mr.AF "...because, fragment is sub-activity..." what are you talking about? No fragment doesn't extend from activity